# Using Flink window and fold function, element missing?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flinkml

When I try to aggregate elements using window and fold function, some
of the elements are missed from getting aggregated. Consuming elements
from Kafka `(value:0, value:1, value:2, value:3)` and aggregating them
as odd and even values.

Output is:

```
{even=[0, 2, 4], odd=[1, 3]}
{even=[6, 8], odd=[5, 7, 9]}
{even=[14, 16, 18], odd=[15, 17]}
{even=[20, 22], odd=[19, 21, 23]}
{even=[24, 26, 28], odd=[25, 27]}
```

Numbers between 10-13 is missing and this happens for a random set of
numbers. Can someone suggest what is missed from the code below and
how can I be sure to process all elements?

```
public static class Splitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, 
    Tuple3<String, String, List<String>>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple3<String, String, 
        List<String>>out) throws Exception {
        String[] vals = value.split(":");

        if(vals.length 1 && Integer.parseInt(vals[1]) % 2 == 0){
            out.collect(new Tuple3<String, String, List<String>>
             ("test","even", Arrays.asList(vals[1])));
        }else{
            out.collect(new Tuple3<String, String, List<String>>
            ("test","odd", Arrays.asList(vals[1])));
        }
    }
}


    DataStream<Map<String, List<String>>streamValue = 
    kafkaStream.flatMap(new Splitter()).keyBy(0)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(3000))).
    trigger(CustomizedCountTrigger.of(5L))//.trigger(CountTrigger.of(2))
    .fold(new HashMap<String, List<String>>(), new 
    FoldFunction<Tuple3<String, String, List<String>>, Map<String, 
    List<String>>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Map<String, List<String>fold(Map<String, 
        List<String>accumulator,
        Tuple3<String, String, List<String>value) throws 
        Exception {
            if(accumulator.get(value.f1) != null){
                List<Stringlist = new ArrayList<>();
                list.addAll(accumulator.get(value.f1));
                list.addAll(value.f2);
                accumulator.put(value.f1, list);
            }else{
                accumulator.put(value.f1, value.f2);
            }
            return accumulator;
        }
    });

    streamValue.print();
    env.execute("window test");
}


public class CustomizedCountTrigger<W extends Windowextends 
Trigger<Object, W{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final long maxCount;

    private final ReducingStateDescriptor<LongstateDesc =
    new ReducingStateDescriptor<>("count", new Sum(), 
    LongSerializer.INSTANCE);

    private CustomizedCountTrigger(long maxCount) {
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, W window,
    TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ReducingState<Longcount = ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDesc);
        count.add(1L);
        if (count.get() >= maxCount) {
            count.clear();
            return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, W window,

    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext

    ctx) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, W window,

    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext

    ctx) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(W window, 
    org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.triggers.Trigger.TriggerContext

    ctx)
    throws Exception {
        ctx.getPartitionedState(stateDesc).clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CountTrigger(" +  maxCount + ")";
    }

    public static <W extends WindowCustomizedCountTrigger<Wof(long 
    maxCount) {
        return new CustomizedCountTrigger<>(maxCount);
    }

    private static class Sum implements ReduceFunction<Long{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Long reduce(Long value1, Long value2) throws Exception {
            return value1 + value2;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*So I started writing the first part of this before noticing your custom triggers make the fact that you are using a TumblingEventTime window sort of irrelevant, but I want to include my original thoughts anyway since I am not fully sure why you would use an EventTime window when you aren't using it. My response after realizing this is below the original.*

Are you running this on a single parallelism or multiple? The reason why I ask is because if it is multiple parallelism (and the kafka topic is also comprised of multiple partitions), then it is possible that messages are being received and processed in a non sequential order. This could lead to messages with a timestamp that causes the watermark to advance, causing the window to process the messages. Then the next message(s) has an event time that is before the current watermark time (a.k.a being "late") and that will cause the message to be dropped.

So for example: if you have 20 elements and the event time of each is like such:

message1: eventTime: 1000
message1: eventTime: 2000
etc...

And your event-time window is 5001ms.

Now messages message1 through message9 come through in order. This first window will be processed and contain messages 1-5 (message6 will have caused the window to be processed). Now if message11 comes in before message10, it will cause the window to be processed containing messages 6-9. And when message10 comes next, the watermark has already advanced past message10's event time, causing it to be dropped as a "late event".

***Proper Answer***

Instead of using an eventTime window and a custom trigger, try using a countWindow.

So replace this:

```
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(3000))).
trigger(CustomizedCountTrigger.of(5L))//.trigger(CountTrigger.of(2))
```

With this:

```
.countWindow(5L)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and explanation. I agree with using eventTimeWindow and resulting in messages getting dropped. But my use case is something like below. Before that, I would clarify by saying I tried using both parallelism(1) and parallelism(2) but issue remained same, some events where dropped.

Comment: My use case is to process a set of events when one of the business logic is evaluated as true. e.g., If total number of events are greater than 3 or total number of events with even number is greater than 5 or predefined time window is crossed(say, 2 seconds). Also, I understood if you override the window trigger with one of our own, then the actual trigger would not be considered anymore., in this case, time elapse of window.      
            
            
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime); env.setParallelism(1); @Jicaar I appreciate your views.

Comment: Including a custom trigger does override the default trigger. But what triggers the custom trigger is still active. So when the TumblingEventTime window of 3000ms is completed, it will trigger the custom onEventTime method in your custom trigger. But you have the onEventTime method set to just continue and not fire and/or purge (whereas the default trigger would have returned FIRE_AND_PURGE), making the event time window essentially pointless, from what I can tell.

Comment: Also, I don't see you calculating the event time of the events so I am guessing you mean to be using processing time instead? But even if you are, that is told to just continue in the custom trigger you have, so nothing would happen.

But if you do want to use eventTime, then have the onEventTime method in your custom trigger return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE. If you mean to use processing time, have your onProcessingTime method in your custom trigger return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE, and change your TumblingEventTimeWindows.of() to a TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of()

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jicaar. This helped to understand it better.